# Buscar una tabla por su nombre dentro de un servidor en SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Necesito buscar la palabra catalogo que es el nombre de una tabla dentro de un servidor que tiene 40 BDD, tengo la consulta:

```
  SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE NAME LIKE '%catalogo%'
```

Pero con esta consulta tengo que meterme a cada `BDD` y ejecutar el `Query` existirá una consulta para hacer la busqueda a nivel servidor ?

Comment: Usa SQL Search. https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cambia el nombre del esquema(dbo) y el nombre de la tabla

```
SELECT name FROM   sys.databases WHERE  CASE
  WHEN state_desc = 'ONLINE' 
  THEN OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(name) + '.[dbo].[Cliente]', 'U')
   END IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Me podrías indicar como usar un LIKE para la búsqueda por nombre de la tabla

Comment: Intenta con esto **EXEC sp_MSforeachdb "use [?];select * from sys.tables where name like '%nombre_tabla%'"**